# Setting up PGF key code inside handler

Tags: pgfkeys

(**Edit**: My original example was too simplistic; here is a more accurate version.)

I would like to traverse all names in a dictionary-like structure representing PGF keys. I would like to associate some code with all such keys. Here is an example demonstrating the issue:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newcounter{traversed}

\newcommand{\traverse}[1]{
  \pgfkeyscurrentkey{}/.begin overlay,
  {
    \pgfkeysalso{
      \pgfkeyscurrentname/.cd,
      .unknown/.code={\traverse{##1}},
      #1
    }
  }
  \pgfkeyscurrentkey{}/.end overlay,
}

\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.begin overlay/.code={%
    \stepcounter{traversed}
    \pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\arabic{traversed}}
  },
  /handlers/.end overlay/.code={
    \pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/last}{\arabic{traversed}}
  },
  /traverse/.is family,
  /traverse/.unknown/.code={\traverse{#1}},
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/traverse,a={b,c},d={e,f}}
% \pgfkeys{\pgfkeys{/traverse,a={b,c},d={e,f}}}

\end{document}
```

If I run this document, its contents are

```
/traverse/a/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/b/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/b/.end overlay,
/traverse/a/c/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/c/.end overlay,
/traverse/a/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/e/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/e/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/f/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/f/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/.end overlay,
```

If I call `\pgfkeys` directly on this output, the keys are defined with the expected values. E.g.,

```
\pgfkeys{
/traverse/a/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/b/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/b/.end overlay,
/traverse/a/c/.begin overlay,
/traverse/a/c/.end overlay,
/traverse/a/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/e/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/e/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/f/.begin overlay,
/traverse/d/f/.end overlay,
/traverse/d/.end overlay,
}
\pgfkeys{/traverse/a}
```

produces 1 in the final document. However, if I uncomment the commented line in the first snippet, TeX runs of of space. I have also tried using `\edef` to store the result of the first call to `\pgfkeys` before passing this result to the second call. But this causes TeX to enter an infinite loop.

Any ideas on how to run the results of the first call to `\pgfkeys`?

Comment: Welcome! Why have you put an extra group around `\pgfkeysalso`? Generally, Ti*k*Z keeps everything within the local group, so that group will keep the settings local.

Comment: It would have been better to leave the original question and ask a followup. As it is, my answer doesn't now make any sense. Sometimes people *add* questions into their questions, but *replacing* the original is just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You've created an extra group around `\pgfkeysalso`, so the effect of setting the keys is confined within that group. If you remove the additional group, the error disappears and the output is as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.traverse/.code={%
    \pgfkeysalso{
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code={Some code}
    }
    traverse \pgfkeyscurrentpath{} \\
  },
  /traverse/.is family
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/traverse/1/.traverse}
\pgfkeys{/traverse/1}

\end{document}
```

[image: target output after removing grouping]

But you shouldn't use `\\`  to end a line outside special cases. Also, `minimal` isn't suitable for minimal examples, despite the name.

Comment: Thanks! I have realized that I had simplified my example too much. I think I do need the extra grouping around `\pgfkeysalso`. I have updated my question with a more accurate use case.